# How to decode text/html utf-8 string ios swift 3

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I'm using [Kanna](https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna) to parse data from html source code.

My code:

```
func parseDataFromHtmlSource() {
    guard let myURL = URL(string: self.url! ) else {
        return
    }
    var myURLString = ""
    do {
        myURLString = try String(contentsOf: myURL, encoding: .ascii)
    } catch let error {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }

    if let doc = HTML(html: myURLString, encoding: .utf8) {

        let item = doc.xpath("//*[@id='pagebody_list']/div/div[1]/div/ul/li[3]/p[2]/text()")
        self.des_content = item.first?.text
    }
}
```

[image: html source]

But the result is:

> Monkey D. Luffy, 1 cáºu bÃ© ráº¥t thÃch háº£i táº·c cÃ³ Æ°á»c mÆ¡ tÃ¬m
>   ÄÆ°á»£c kho bÃ¡u One Piece vÃ  trá» thÃ nh Vua háº£i táº·c - Pirate
>   King. LÃºc nhá», Luffy tÃ¬nh cá» Än pháº£i trÃ¡i quá» (Devil Fruit)
>   Gomu Gomu, nÃ³ cho cÆ¡ thá» cáºu kháº£ nÄng co dÃ£n ÄÃ n há»i nhÆ° cao
>   su nhÆ°ng Äá»i láº¡i cáºu sáº½ khÃ´ng bao giá» biáº¿t bÆ¡i. Sau ÄÃ³
>   Luffy láº¡i ÄÆ°á»£c Shank cá»©u thoÃ¡t tuy nhiÃªn Ã´ng ta bá» máº¥t 1
>   cÃ¡nh tay. Sau Äáº¥y Shank chia tay Luffy vÃ  Äá» láº¡i cho cáºu cÃ¡i
>   mÅ© rÆ¡m (Straw Hat) vÃ  nÃ³i ráº±ng: \"Sau nÃ y bao giá» thÃ nh
>   cÆ°á»p biá»n hÃ£y gáº·p ta vÃ  tráº£ láº¡i nÃ³\". ChÃnh lá»i nÃ³i nÃ y
>   ÄÃ£ thÃºc Äáº§y Luffy trá» thÃ nh 1 cÆ°á»p biá»n tháºt sá»±

I want my String like in the picture above. Do you have any idea to fix it?

Comment: Try other encodings. The source is most likely not ASCII. Look into the header of the html code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace ".ascii" to ".utf8". Have fun 
`do {
        myURLString = try String(contentsOf: myURL, encoding: .utf8)
    } catch let error {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }`

Comment: Perfect! Thank a million for your help :D